# Use of unresolved identifier 'checkForWin' and Invalid redeclaration of 'aiDeciding()'

Tags: swift

I was following along a swift tutorial when suddenly an error appeared, I've written the code exactly as the guy on YouTube.

I would really appreciate an answer if you know how to fix the bug.

(: From a 13 year old programmer.

```
var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
    }

checkForWin()
    aiTurn()

}

func setImageForSpot(spot:Int,player:Int) {

}

func chekForWin(){


}

func aiDeciding() {

}
func aiTurn() {


}
```

Comment: Please post the code and provide a link to the YouTube tutorial.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You might want to have a look [ask] which contains good advice about asking good questions in this forum, such as  *"But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some."* and *"...  take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense?"*

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called `aiDeciding` and a function `func aiDeciding()` with same name. It looks like a bug.

And you have made a typo in `chekForWin` instead of `checkForWin`.